A special kind of Poisson summation formula
There is a Poisson summation formula as follows:
Let $V$ be a smooth function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$.  For $X > 1$ and $q > 1$, we have
$$\sum_{n\equiv a~\mathrm{ mod }~q}{V}\left( \frac{n}{X} \right) =\frac{X}{q}\sum_{h\in \mathbb{Z}}{\widehat{V}\left( \frac{hX}{q} \right) \mathrm{e}\left( \frac{ha}{q} \right)},$$
where $e(x):=e^{2\pi ix}$ and $$\widehat{V}(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}V(t)e(-xt)dt$$ is the fourier transform of $V$.
May I ask if anyone can prove it?

We have that
$$\frac{1}{q} \sum_{b = 1}^{q} e\left(\frac{(a - n)b}{q}\right) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \equiv a \pmod{q}, \\
0 & \text{if } n \not\equiv a \pmod{q}.
\end{cases}$$
So
$$\sum_{\substack{n = -\infty \\ n \equiv a \pmod{q}}}^{\infty} V\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{b = 1}^{q} e\left(\frac{ab}{q}\right) \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} V\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) e\left(-\frac{bn}{q}\right).$$
The Fourier transform of the summand is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V\left(\frac{x}{X}\right) e\left(-\frac{bx}{q}\right) e(-x\xi) \, dx = X \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V(x) e\left(-xX\left(\frac{b}{q} + \xi\right)\right) \, dx.$$
So by the Poisson summation formula,
$$\sum_{\substack{n = -\infty \\ n \equiv a \pmod{q}}}^{\infty} V\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) = \frac{X}{q} \sum_{b = 1}^{q} e\left(\frac{ab}{q}\right) \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{V}\left(X\left(\frac{b}{q} + n\right)\right).$$
We make the change of variables $n \mapsto (n - b)/q$, so that the right-hand side becomes
$$\sum_{\substack{n = -\infty \\ n \equiv a \pmod{q}}}^{\infty} V\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) = \frac{X}{q} \sum_{b = 1}^{q} e\left(\frac{ab}{q}\right) \sum_{\substack{n = -\infty \\ n \equiv b \pmod{q}}}^{\infty} \widehat{V}\left(\frac{nX}{q}\right) = \frac{X}{q} \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{V}\left(\frac{nX}{q}\right) e\left(\frac{an}{q}\right).$$

Thank you !  Indeed, it is used in analytic number theory.  May I ask if there is a more general result such that this Poisson summation formula is only an example ?
